# A little hint about an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, lua, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I need an algorithm that goes from point_a to point_b spending a given n pixels(or I could consider squares [with the area larger than a pixel] as being one pixel).
For example:
if, in the cartesian plan, point_a = (0,0) and point_b = (100, 150), and n = 350, I want the algorithm to behave this way:
if point_a + point_b equals n, then it goes straight to the final point(i.e. x = 100, y = 150)
but if the condition above is false, it keeps walking around the plan until the above condition becomes true, and when it does, it goes straight to the point.

I was thinking about something of the algorithm I cited above. My problem is that the algorithm can't spend either more or less than n, it has to be exatcly n.

I'm currently using Lua, but that doesnt matter, cause what I want here is actually improve my idea, not get another one ready to go.

Comment: What does point_a + point_b mean?

Comment: you need to define "walking around the plan until the above condition becomes true, and when it does, it goes straight to the point"

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I think he means if the straight line path between the points equals n, then you're done, else find a wandering path to expend some of n until you reach a point where the straight line path to point_b equals what remains of n.

Comment: I think I understand your description, but I'm not clear what your question is. Where are you having a problem?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth forgeting about the (x, y) point_a and point_b cordinates, and thinking of it as a unique number, the correct way would be "if point_b - point_a = n, then goes straight to the point". So its exactly what hatchet said. sorry about that.

Comment: @hatchet My problem is: I need a way to spend exatcly n steps, i.e. (point_b.x - point_a.x) + (point_b.y - point_a.y).

Comment: @hatchet my problem is exactly what you said, what you're not getting then?

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, you can't move diagonally (as 1 step). In that case, the problem isn't necessarily solvable - a solution may or may not exist, this can be seen in the trivial case of (1,1) -> (2,2) with n = 3.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Let's say, in that case we can sum 1 step.

Comment: Are you looking for an in some way "natural-looking" path? Or a random-looking one maybe? The problem is easily solvable by taking the shortest route to the target, but stop 1 move away (if you would move into the target, do not move, stop). From there, you go 1 move in the opposite direction and back until you have either 1 or 0 moves left, then move into the target. This will (assuming N is not smaller than the shortest path) take N or N+1 moves. Do you maybe want to avoid moving into the same cell multiple times?

Comment: Also, if you want to first do the "walking around", then move to the target, of course you could calculate the length of the shortest path without moving, substract it from n, first "burn through" your extra moves by going left-right-left-right etc, then move to target.

Comment: of course I don't wanna step through the same path twice. But, your second algorithm is pretty much what I want to do. I'll just alter the way how it spends the extra moves(the remainder of n - lenght_shortest_path, as you said), and instead of going left and right, it'll make a more "rational path". Anyway, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any preference about how the path should look like? How about let the algorithm first travel the straight line and then keep go back and forth at the final square until all steps are used up? Or a slightly better looking algorithm would look like something like this:

Say pointA is (0,0), pointB is (0,p), now find pointC (x,0) such that path A->C->B has a length of n. Easily you can get x = sqrt(n^2 - p^2). In case n==p, c=0 which means just go for the straight line.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what distance measure you are using. If you start at (0,0) and want to go to (3,4), then is is 5 steps (euclidean distance) or 7 steps (manhattan distance)? If you are using euclidean distance, how do you deal with irrational distances?

I am assuming you are using manhattan distance and I am proposing a probabilistic solution.

Let us assume you are m steps away from destination and you need to do that in n steps (n>=m). Let us define current state as (m,n). If you move one step towards the goal, the problem state is (m-1,n-1) and farther from destination, then state is (m+1,n-1).

At each point calculate probability of going towards destination using the *current* state p =  3*m/(3*m + (n-m) ). Generate a random number between 0 and 1 and if it lower than p then go towards the destination, otherwise go farther from destination.

```
def nextmove(m,n):
    p = 3.0*m/(3*m + (n-m) )
    if random.random() <=p:
        return m-1,n-1,'towards'
    else:
        return m+1,n-1,'farther'
```